# PHP, indexing mysql ID in json. Is it worth it?

Tags: php, mysql, json, file, indexing

I have a database in which i've got a table where im having question to be displayed randomly on the main site (about 80 for now). Im reading all the IDs from the database and then randomly selecting one and doing next query to get all the rest needed data of this one. And im curious if should i leave this like that or would it be bether to store all the IDs in .json file and just update it every time i add a question. What is bether? Thanks for help.

Comment: Depends on what database you use. If the field is indexed its probably already fast enough. The json approach makes sense if you have a high number of customers. This would reduce loading times.

Comment: @paskl _This would reduce loading times_ What??? A database is always better than a text file for storing information.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Reading a JSON file once and randomly picking is probably faster, but the real question is if it matters. A 1ms database call is not going to be a problem unless the load is absolutely crushing and relentless.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just interested in a random record from the table, just do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1;
```

All in one query and you don't have to retrieve a list of IDs first.

And it's almost always a bad idea to maintain two separate data sources.

Comment: This is the way to go. But if the table grows a lot it can become slow as it will order all the rows before selecting the first. In that case it can be better having the ID selected from the app.

Comment: If you have a big table, [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) has faster algorithms.